# How to replace some characters with asterisks except first four characters

Tags: php, string, email

I want to hide some characters from my email address like

**Current add :** `example@gmail.com`
**Using my code :** `*******@gmail.com`
**I want it like** : `exam***@gmail.com`

My code:

```
function hide_mail($email) {
    $mail_part = explode("@", $email);
    $mail_part[0] = str_repeat("*", strlen($mail_part[0]));
    return implode("@", $mail_part);
}

echo hide_mail("example@gmail.com");
```

Comment: You can't hide email address from mail. but if you wish to hide email address from email than please use mail's bcc method.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `substr()` you do this.

**PHP**

```
<?php        
    function hide_mail($email) {
        $new_mail = "";
        $mail_part1 = explode("@", $email);
        $mail_part2 = substr($mail_part1[0],4); // Sub string after fourth character.
        $new_mail = substr($mail_part1[0],0,4); // Add first four character part.
        $new_mail .= str_repeat("*", strlen($mail_part2))."@"; // Replace *. And add @
        $new_mail .= $mail_part1[1]; // Add last part.
        return $new_mail;
    }

    echo hide_mail("example@gmail.com");
?>
```

**Output**

```
exam***@gmail.com
```

Comment: Great Bro that works like super cool, Thanks But if possible can you explain it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split `$mail_part[0]` at the forth character.

Do your replace with *'s on the second part of that split, then join the three parts together again.